# How to compress string and store in redis using python

Tags: python, redis, compression

I would like to store all my string using Utf8 String Codec with GZIP in python.

I tried below code but compression not happening properly. I don't know what's missing here. How to insert data into redis using gzip compression technique.

After insertion into redis it just printing some number like d49

```
import redis
import StringIO
import gzip

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=80, db=0, decode_responses=True)

out = StringIO.StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode='w') as f:
    value = f.write('this is my test value')
    r.set('test', value)
```

Appreciated your help in advance!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use compress() method of gzip.

*If you are directly compressing the text string,*

```
import redis
import gzip

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=80, db=0, decode_responses=True)
text = 'this is my test value'
value = gzip.compress(text.encode())
r.set('test', value)
```

*If you are trying to compress the file,*

```
import redis
import gzip

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=80, db=0, decode_responses=True)
with open('text.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    value = gzip.compress(fp.read())
    r.set('test', value)
```

Comment: Which python version you are using? It's working in python 3.5.